# Login wih the same login_check Sonata User bundle and Sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I got a app who has `Sonata User bundle` and `Sonata Admin bundle`, but when I login with
Sonata User bundle, and after I try to go to the admin page, I have to do login again,

Some Know how to ingrate both, to just has one login

Thanks any advice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found the solution, I put the same `check_path` and `login_path`  in the **admin firewall** that take by default in the **main firewall**, 
Here I share the code in the security.yml:

# -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL

```
    admin:
        pattern:      /(.*)
        fr3d_ldap:    
            check_path:     /login_check
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
            default_target_path: /admin/
        logout:
            path:           /logout
        anonymous:    true
```

# -> end custom configuration

# defaut login area for standard users

```
   main:
        pattern:      .*
        fr3d_ldap:        ~
        form_login:
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /
```

I hope this help to someone!!

Comment: I had the same problem. That's because in the SonataAdmin documentation they give a different firewall for the admin by default. But the [Symfony2 Security documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form) actually tells that "Multiple firewalls don't share security context". That's why you have to use only one firewall if you need a global authentication (that I think is the most common case)

Answer (score 0):

When you are login with firewall "admin" the firewall "main" doesn't know about you, because SESSION is writting with default prefix (name of the firewall).
You need to use 1 contex for different firewalls (in app/config/security.yml):

```
admin:
        pattern: /admin(.*)
        context: user
        form_login:
         .....

main:
        pattern: ^/
        context: user
        form_login:
        .....
```

> context: user